# How to pass dynamic content from form using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to pass data filled in a form, so it would be sent in a POST request using the Ajax code.

Here is my HTML form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Alteon Cluster Management</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="alteon1.js"></script>  

    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="configR1btn">Configure Server 1</button> <button id="configR2btn">Configure Server 2</button>
        <form>
                <section>
                    <header>
                    <h1>R Servers</h1>
                </header>
                    Server 1 IP Address:    <input type ="text" name="firstRServerIP"><br><br>
                    Server 1 Name:          <input type ="text" name="firstRServerName"><br><br>

                    Server 2 IP Address:    <input type ="text" name="secondRServerIP"><br><br>
                    Server 2 Name:          <input type ="text" name="secondRServerName"><br><br>
                </section>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                $('#configR1btn').click(function (){
                    var t = $(this);
                    //var t.closest(".form").find(".firstRServerIP").val();
                    var firstRServerIP = t.prev(".firstRServerIP").val();
                    var dataString = '{\n"State":"2"\n"IpAddr":" + firstRServerIP"\n}';

                        $.ajax({
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        url: 'https://Default_Generated_Alteon_BBI_Cert/config/SlbNewCfgEnhRealServerTable/R1',
                                        //crossDomain: true,
                                        data: dataString,
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                                var value = responseData.someKey;
                                                },
                                        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                                alert('POST failed.');
                                                }
                                });

                        });
});
```

For example, I fill the data '1.2.3.4' in the "firstRServerIP" part of the HTML form, and click the "Configure" button.
The POST request data should look like this:

```
{
"State":"2"
"IpAddr":"1.2.3.4"
}
```

Instead, I get:

```
{
"State":"2"
"IpAddr":   "  firstRServerIP"
}
```

What is wrong with my code?
A help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: do it like this -> `var dataString = {State : 2, IpAddr : firstRServerIP};`

Comment: You should serialize your FORM data instead of trying to build it like this manually  http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

You can correct it like that:

```
var dataString = '{\n"State":"2"\n"IpAddr":"' + firstRServerIP + '"\n}';
```

But I would suggest you to do that instead:

```
var dataString = JSON.stringify({
        State: '2'
        IpAddr: t.prev(".firstRServerIP").val()
    })
;
```

You can also do the following if you want all the values of your form:

```
var dataString = $('#my-form').serialize();
```

in this case set the good `name` attributes in your inputs (ie. `State` and `IpAddr`) and use `<form id="my-form">`

Comment: Tried using
var dataString = '{\n"State":"2"\n"IpAddr":"' + firstRServerIP + '"\n}';
But I get:

{
"State":"2"
"IpAddr":"undefined"
}:

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, got my comment sent before finishing it...
The POST is sent with the following data:
{
"State":"2"
"IpAddr":"undefined"
}:
Any idea?

Comment: Use `var firstRServerIP = t.closest('form').find('.firstRServerIP').val()`, then add a class to your input `<input type="text" name="firstRServerIP" class="firstRServerIP" />` and set your button inside the form `<form><button></button><button></button>...</form>` (not outside like in your example).

Comment: Added the class, but still get "undefined":

{
"State":"2"
"IpAddr":"undefined"
}:

I had the button inside the form, but when I do that, a GET request is being sent instead of POST.
I'll fix that later, now I'm more interested in passing the data filled in the form, to the POST request.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not `t.closest('.form')` but `t.closest('form')`.

Comment: Tried it as well, still "undefined".

Comment: You can try just using `$('.firstRServerIP').val()`. If it is working you certainly have something misplaced.

Comment: Got it!
With $('.firstRServerIP').val() and "class" added to the form.
And I also had a missing ";" at the end of one of the vars.

Thanks @Gnucki!

Comment: Glad if I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the format of your `dataString` object so that it's more readable and also used a different jQuery selector to get the value from the proper input field.

```
$('#configR1btn').click(function () {
        var firstRServerIP = $("[name='firstRServerIP']").val();
        var dataString = {
            "State":"2",
            "IpAddr": firstRServerIP
        };
        console.log(dataString);
```

This will output:

[image]

You can play with this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamback42/sg0m9sp0/7/). Open your console to see the result of the click.

Comment: Almost there!
Now, I filled in the data "1.1.1.1" and the POST is sent without quotes and without the "{" and "}" characters at the beginning and end:

State:2
IpAddr:1.1.1.1

Any idea?

Comment: Where do you see the code without the characters?  I feel sure that the brackets are really there and that the JSON object is formatted correctly per the example on JSFiddle.

Comment: I see the code without the characters on chrome debugger.
So, the actual POST request packets is sent like this:

State:2
IpAddr:1.1.1.1

Comment: I updated my answer to show what the output in my Chrome console looks like.

Comment: Strange.
I just added your code to mine...
Can you share you full code?

Comment: Still sending the POST without quotes and "{" marks...
Very strange.
Any idea why?

Comment: Is this causing the POST request to error? It may appear without {} and quotes because they are inferred by the JSON dataType.

Comment: Yes, it is causing POST request error (406 Not Acceptable).

Comment: @UdiDahan, 406 means that the server response is not acceptable. It does not indicate an error with what your are sending. This [site](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html) about 406 says, "If the Web server detects that the data it wants to return is not acceptable to the client, it returns a header containing the 406 error code." Please look at the link to see their suggested fixes.

Comment: @Adamn.
Thanks, I understand what 406 means and in my case, the server responded with that code because it received the JSON data without quotes.
Never mind, we fixed that.
Thanks!

Comment: var dataString = '{\n"State":"2"\n"IpAddr":"' + firstRServerIP + '"\n}';
This syntax works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need. Please bear in mind that you do not have an element with `class="firstRServerIP"`; therefore `$('.firstRServerIP').val()` will always return `undefined`.

```
$('#configR1btn').click(function (){
     var f = $('form').first(),
         firstRServerIP = f.find(':text[name=firstRServerIP]').val(),
         dataString = JSON.stringify({ 
             State: "2", 
             IpAddr: firstRServerIP 
     });
     dataString = dataString.replace(/([\{,])/g,'$1\n').replace('}','\n}');
     $.ajax(...........
```

**PROOF OF CONCEPT**

```js
$('#configR1btn').on('click',function() {
  var f = $('form').first(),
      firstRServerIP = f.find(':text[name=firstRServerIP]').val(),
      dataString = JSON.stringify({ 
        State: "2", 
        IpAddr: firstRServerIP 
      });
  dataString = dataString.replace(/([\{,])/g,'$1\n').replace('}','\n}');

  alert( dataString );
  //ajax call here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="configR1btn">Configure Server 1</button> <button id="configR2btn">Configure Server 2</button>
        <form>
                <section>
                    <header>
                    <h1>R Servers</h1>
                </header>
                    Server 1 IP Address:    <input type ="text" name="firstRServerIP"><br><br>
                    Server 1 Name:          <input type ="text" name="firstRServerName"><br><br>

                    Server 2 IP Address:    <input type ="text" name="secondRServerIP"><br><br>
                    Server 2 Name:          <input type ="text" name="secondRServerName"><br><br>
                </section>

        </form>
```

Comment: With this code, the POST looks like this:
{"State":2}:

Comment: Now looks like this:
{"State":"2"}:

Comment: Yes, "IpAddr": "1.1.1.1" is not included, and there is no new line between the "{" and "State"... and between "2" and "}", while there should be new line.

Comment: Not sure I understand why that would happen but I have updated my answer.